# Combo drive doesn't read discs

Tags: windows, dvd, bios, blu-ray

I bought a brand new Samsung SH-B083L/BSBP for my new computer.  It's detected in the bios but it is unable to boot from any media.  After installing windows using another disc drive, windows detects the Samsung drive, but no media can be read from the drive.  Any disc inserted will be ejected upon double clicking the disc's icon upon which I will be informed that I need to insert a disc.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have a faulty drive. Return it and get a new one.

Comment: That's what I figured.  I RMA'd it just now.